# python glob matching patterns

Tags: python, c, glob

I am looking at the glob man page and I cannot make the matching patterns work in python. I have this so far...

```
glob.glob('file.*') + glob.glob('file[0-9].*')
```

and this works and return me a list as long as the file numbers o not exceed 9. If I make a file100.txt it does not work, and if I try the range [0-100] or [0-1000] it does not change anything...

So my question is how can I make this match any number....and also how can I combine it into one statement, it seems like it should be once statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `glob` isn't expressive enough to do what you want, so I suggest fetching more than you need and then filtering. E.g. (untested)

```
import re

file_names = [name for name in glob.glob('file*.*') if re.match(r'^file\d*\.', name]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary globbing doesn't handle that type of thing.  You can't specify repetitions of specific patterns of characters.  You won't be able to do it with a single call.  Your best bet is to just use `file*.txt`, and then post-process the resulting list to eliminate ones not matching your pattern, for instance by using regular expressions functions in the `re` module.